# How to determine the sync status is up to date for particular node in a Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

Suppose I have two node `cassandra` cluster and they are reside on physically different data-centers. Suppose the database inside that cluster has replication factor is `2` which means every data in that database should be sync with each other. suppose this database is a massive database which have millions of records of its tables. I named those nodes centers as `node1` and `node2`. Suppose `node2` is not reliable and there was a crash on that server and take few days to fix and get the server back to up and running state. After that according to my understating there should be a gap between `node1` and `node2` and it may take significant time to sync `node2` with `node1`. So need a way to measure the gap between `node2` and node1 for the mean time of sync happen? After some times how should I assure that `node2` is equal to `node1`? Please correct me if im wrong with this question according to the cassandra architechure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's start with your description. 2 node cluster, which sounds fine, but 2 nodes in 2 different data centers (DCs) - bad design, but doable. Each data center should have multiple nodes to ensure your data is highly available. Anyway, that aside, let's assume you have a 2 node cluster with 1 node in each DC. The replication factor (RF) is defined at the keyspace level (not at the cluster level - each DC will have a RF setting for a particular keyspace (or 0 if not specified for a particular DC)). That being said, you can't have RF=2 for a keyspace for either of your DCs if you only have a single node in each one (RF, which is how many copies of the data that exist, can't be more than the number of nodes in the DC). So let's put that aside for now as well.

You have the possibility for DCs to become out of sync as well as nodes within a DC to become out of sync. There are multiple protections against this problem.

Consistency Level (CL)
This is a lever that you (the client) have to be able to help control how far out of sync things get. There's a trade off between availability v.s. consistency (with performance implications as well). The CL setting is configured at connection time and/or each statement level. For writes, the CL determines how many nodes must IMMEDIATELY ACKNOWLEDGE the write before giving your application the "green light" to move on (a number of nodes that you're comfortable with - knowing the more nodes you immediately require the more consistent your nodes and/or DC(s) will be, but the longer it will take and the less flexibility you have in nodes becoming unavailable without client failure). If you specify less than RF it doesn't mean that RF won't be met, it just means that they don't need to immediately acknowledge the write to move on. For reads, this setting determines how many nodes' data are compared before the result is returned (if cassandra finds a particular row doesn't match from the nodes it's comparing, it will "fix" them during the read before you get your results - this is called read repair). There are a handful of CL options by the client (e.g. ONE, QUORUM, LOCAL_ONE, LOCAL_QUOURM, etc.). Again, there is a trade-off between availability and consistency with the selected choice.

If you want to be sure your data is consistent when your queries run (when you read the data), ensure the write CL + the read CL > RF. You can ensure that's done on a LOCAL level (e.g. the DC that the read/write is occurring on, say, LOCAL_QUORUM) or globally (all DCs with QUORUM). By doing this, you'll be sure that while your cluster may be inconsistent, your results during reads will not be (i.e. the results will be consistent/accurate - which is all that anyone really cares about). With this setting you also allow some flexibility in unavailable nodes (e.g. for a 3 node DC you could have a single node be unavailable without client failure for either reads or writes).

If nodes do become out of sync, you have a few options at this point:

Repair
Repair (run by "nodetool repair") - this is a facility that you can schedule or manually run to reconcile your tables, keyspaces and/or the entire node with other nodes (either in the DC the node resides or the entire cluster). This is a "node level" command and must be run on each node to "fix" things. If you have DSE, Ops Center can run repairs in the background fixing "chunks" of data - cycling the process repetitively.

NodeSync
Similar to repair, this is a DSE specific tool similar to repair that helps keep data in sync (the newer version of repair).

Unavailable nodes:

Hinted Handoff
Cassandra has the ability to "hold onto" changes if nodes become unavailable during writes. It will hang onto changes for a specified period of time. If the unavailable nodes become available before time runs out, the changes are sent over for application. If time runs out, hint collection stops and one of the other options, above, need to be performed to catch things up.

Finally, there is no way to know how inconsistent things are (e.g. 30% inconsistent). You simply try to utilize the tools mentioned above to control consistency without completely sacrificing availability.

Hopefully that makes sense and helps.

-Jim

Comment: I think the meaning of the datacenter terminology is deference with the cassandra perspective. According to my question I assume both node1 and node2 are in a same DC logically in cassandra level. But physically they are in two deferent datacenters.

Comment: How do I identiy whether my node need a `nodetool repair` or not? can I identify that from `nodetool status` output ?

Comment: There is no way to 100% know the status of your cluster (whether it needs repair or not). Typically you'll find out from the application teams stating things don't look "right" (e.g. inconsistent results with repetitive queries). If cassandra never comes down and you run a "nodetool tpstats" and look for "dropped mutations", you may get some indication if things are ok or not, but the info is only from the last cassandra restart.

Comment: It seems cassandra is not realiable. Suppose if a application read critical data from a node which really needs repair may cause to display false result. we can't let the detecting the false result from the application level.So I think this should be handle inside in the cassandra engine. if not it is a drawback of cassandra. Actually I experienced the deference results for repetitive queries. At that time I was wonder.

Comment: Actually Cassandra consistency is configurable, which I think is absolutely awesome - especially for a distributed system. The application is in control of how consistent they want the data to be, with the trade-off of availability and performance. So if you want consistent data all of the time, have the client CL for reads + writes > replication factor (RF). For example, if all traffic goes to a single DC, then set CL to LOCAL_QUORUM for reads and writes. If activity goes to multiple DCs, choose QUORUM instead. Data will be consistent during reads. That's just one example.

Comment: As a side comment to my above comment, configuring a DC with only 2 nodes is not a good idea. It's really no better than 1 node for your consistency/availability concerns. The reason is because, assuming RF=2 (all), CL of QUORUM = 2 = all = no nodes down without noticeable failures. CL < QUORUM means you can have consistency issues. To solve that, 3 nodes would be the minimum to allow for "reasonable" configuration of consistency and availability. Setting RF=3 (RF=2 still causes issues), QUORUM = 2, which means you can have one unavailable node, and yet allow for consistent reads.